# Override Dockerfile arguments by Kubernetes Deployment.yml

Tags: docker, kubernetes, gitlab, dockerfile, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm running a pipeline on gitlab which uses .gitlab-ci.yml and Dockerfile to build a image and push it to GCP container repository. Then I use that image to make deployment on Kubernetes.

I'm using CI/CD private variables to inject **username(service_now_qa_username)** and **password(service_now_qa_password)** and passing it as arguments to docker build command which are then used in **Dockerfile**

This is what my gitlab-ci.yml file looks like

```
variables:
        BUILD_ARGS: "--build-arg USERNAME=$service_now_qa_username --build-arg PASSWORD=$service_now_qa_password"
script:
   
    - docker build -t "$IMAGE_NAME:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME" -t "$IMAGE_NAME:latest" $BUILD_ARGS .
```

This is what my Dockerfile looks like:

```
ARG USERNAME
ARG PASSWORD
ENV USER=$USERNAME
ENV PASS=$PASSWORD

ENTRYPOINT java -jar servicenowapi.jar -conf config.json -username ${USER} -password ${PASS}
```

Now I want to override these arguments of **username** and **password** using Kubernetes **Deployment.yml** and use Deployment.yaml file to override these arguments.

My end goal is to use Kubernetes Deployment.yaml for **username** and **password** and passed as arguments to Dockerfile.

Comment: You need to override the entire entrypoint line. Those are build time variables, not runtime.

Comment: The variable references `$USER` and `$PASS` should be expanded by the shell created by the `ENTRYPOINT` line when the container is launched, and the Kubernetes `env:` block should be able to set these.  Note that the `ARG` values can be retrieved via `docker inspect` by anyone who has the image; you should not publish credentials this way.

Answer (score 3):

`ARGS` are build-time variables so no way to pass values to ARGS at runtime.

By the way, you can override `entrypoint` as following in Kubernetes deployment and consume environment variables. (`entrypoint` in Dockerfile is `command` in Kubernetes container spec).

```bash
containers:
  - name: xxxx
    env:
    - name: USER
      value: "Input your user"
    - name: PASS
      value: "Input your pass"
    command: ["java", "-jar servicenowapi.jar -conf config.json -username $(USER) -password $(PASS)"]
```

The main thing here is to define env vars and to use `$()` instead of `${}`.